# Heroku precompilation issue during Deployment

Tags: heroku

My blog application works fine in my local system. When deployed into heroku (running the command  `git push heroku master`), displays the error message below.

`$ heroku logs`:

```
←[36m2013-06-06T13:47:12.088604+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Enable Logplex by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:47:12.124367+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v2 created by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[33m2013-06-06T13:49:04.948939+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation started
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:13.634734+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.265176+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK resource by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.311667+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v3 created by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.389500+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Add DATABASE_URL config by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.427605+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v4 created by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.482323+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Add  config by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.525116+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v5 created by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.594162+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 6a6f8c4 by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.626530+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v6 created by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[36m2013-06-06T13:50:14.673516+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 6a6f8c4 by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[33m2013-06-06T13:50:15.246348+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:17.919537+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 25897`
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:19.090635+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 44971`
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:22.122895+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be
 removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the
 release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environm
ent.rb:4)
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:22.122511+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be
 removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the
 release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environm
ent.rb:4)
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:24.642253+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Call with -d to detach
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:24.642253+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:24.642253+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44971
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:24.642253+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:24.642253+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:25.465482+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:25.469922+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=44971
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:25.469327+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:25] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:28.407291+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:28.947257+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:28] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:28.947257+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:29.804418+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be
 removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the
 release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environm
ent.rb:4)
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:29.806233+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be
 removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the
 release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environm
ent.rb:4)
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:38.739547+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:38.739385+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:40.615604+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 137
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:43.184019+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:43.184019+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25897
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:43.184019+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Call with -d to detach
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:43.184019+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:43.184019+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:44.564998+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:44.565629+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=25897
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:44.564998+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2013-06-06 13:50:44] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
←[32m2013-06-06T13:50:45.800915+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to up
←[36m2013-06-06T13:51:17.543035+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by lotus123.2008@hotmail.com
←[35m2013-06-06T13:51:20.060927+00:00 heroku[run.9222]:←[0m Awaiting client
←[35m2013-06-06T13:51:20.097882+00:00 heroku[run.9222]:←[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
←[35m2013-06-06T13:51:20.930432+00:00 heroku[run.9222]:←[0m State changed from starting to up
←[35m2013-06-06T13:51:25.519513+00:00 heroku[run.9222]:←[0m Process exited with status 0
←[35m2013-06-06T13:51:25.529067+00:00 heroku[run.9222]:←[0m State changed from up to complete
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:35.161228+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 59.92.36.151 at 2013-06-06 13:51:35 +0000
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:35.440765+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:35.849608+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (55.2ms)
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.112603+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 672ms
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%=stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (application.js isn't precompiled):
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>Blog</title>
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag  "test" %>
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__703185640808623364
_34573040'
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129671+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     10:
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129919+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2013-06-06T13:51:36.129919+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[31m2013-06-06T13:51:36.132423+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path=/ host=still-earth-6287.herokuapp.com fwd="59.92.36.151" dyno=web.1 connect=5m
s service=1084ms status=500 bytes=643
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:09.885182+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 59.92.36.151 at 2013-06-06 14:54:09 +0000
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:09.961981+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:09.968827+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.016285+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (application.js isn't precompiled):
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     5:
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4:   <title>Blog</title>
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     6:   <%=stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag  "test" %>
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__703185640808623364
_34573040'
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053935+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053935+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2013-06-06T14:54:10.053734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     10:
←[31m2013-06-06T14:54:10.084893+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path=/ host=still-earth-6287.herokuapp.com fwd="59.92.36.151" dyno=web.1 connect=7m
s service=328ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Your help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

"application.js isn't precompiled" is your error.  You have a few options:

1) precompile the assets with `rake assets:precompile` on your local machine and add them to your repo (simple, but not very robust in the long run)

2) get assets to precompile when you upload them to Heroku.

Did you get any errors during the push to Heroku?